# Teams in osTicket?

Tags: ticket-system, osticket

I've just started working on osTicket. I'm digging this ticket system to understand more of it. I read a lot about its feature from official website as well as some forums but still I could not figure out the purpose of teams. Can you explain - with some practical example, use of this teams feature and how I may help me in making it work for an education institute with multiple campuses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Team feature gives you the ability to group staff members together (e.g across different departments) for the purpose of ticket assignment (manual or auto).

For example -- you might want a "Data management" team to handle tickets request dealing with data request.